# How to add custom customer attribute in customer edit account page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I want to edit the custom customer attribute in the Customer edit Account page. I  have created a module and its showing it in the admin customer i want it to show it in the frontend customer information edit page..just like First name and last name.

Comment: Hey Subin, just curious if any of the answers helped you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had this question too, and found my answer in this blog article: http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-add-custom-eav-attribute-to-category-or-customer

Answer (score 0):

You need to override customer account edit page template in your custom theme or custom extension. Then you can add that field manually same like firstname and lastname. It will be automatically saved when you update it.